# Trouble with exerise in super basic topology

Tags: general-topology

Given spaces $X,Y$, a closed $A$ in $X$, and a closed map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, I was told to:

> Prove the quotient topology induced on $f(A)$ is equal to the subset topology on $B=fA$ induced by the quotient topology on $Y$.

What is the quotient topology on $Y$?

So far I know that under the quotient topology on $f A$ we have $U\subset f A$ is closed iff $f^{-1} U\subset f^{-1} fA$ is closed.

Taking the subspace topology, since $A$ is closed we have $U\subset fA$ is closed iff $U\subset Y$ is closed.

I don't see where the closedness of $f$ comes into play here either...

Comment: What is B? You haven't defined it.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski sorry, corrected

Comment: There does seem to be a problem with the question. From my understanding the function would have to be surjective in order to have a quotient topology induced by $f$.

Comment: Super basic ???

Comment: @TimRaczkowski but then there's no point in defining $fA=B$, no?

Comment: That's not true. Remember that the domain of $f$ is $X$ not $A$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski okay, but even supposing it is surjective, I still don't see how to combine what I've found into an actual answer :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer a different question, which is probably what was the intended question. Let's prove this instead

Prove the quotient topology induced on $B:=f(A)$ is equal to the subset topology on $B$ induced by the topology on $Y$ (no quotient).

Let $U\subset B$ be an open set in the subspace topology. Then there is an open set $V\subset Y$ such that $V\cap B=U$. Since $A$ is closed and $f$ is closed, $f(A)=B$ is closed in $Y$ and the complement of $U$ in $B$ is $(V\cap B)^c\cap B=V^c\cup B^c\cap B=V^c\cap B$, which is closed in $Y$. Since $f$ is continuous, the preimage of closed sets under $f$ are closed in $X$. Since $f$ is surjective onto $f(A)=B$, this means
$$f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}((V^c\cap B)^c)=f^{-1}(V^c)^c\cap f^{-1}(B)^c$$
is open.

Similarly, if $U\subset B$ is such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)^c$ is closed in $X$ and $f(f^{-1}(U)^c)=U^c\cap B$ is closed in $Y$. Hence $(U^c\cap B)^c=U\cup B^c$ is open. But then $U=(U\cup B^c)\cap B$ is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: $f$ was not said to be continuous

Comment: @popo Ok, but the way the question was posed makes no sense. The proof I gave answers a different question and assumes continuity of $f$...whether or not this was the intended question is a different story. I would ask the person who asked it to clarify.